# Bash: Error reporting flow suddenly changes value from 1 to 0

Tags: bash, unix

I'm writing some code for class on error reporting, and I ran into an odd problem that my teacher couldn't figure out. It looks something like this.

```
function errorCheck(){
if ! firstError $*
then 
return $?
elif ! secondError $*
then
return $?
fi
```

where firstError and secondError are other functions that check for certain error conditions. The return value then feeds into another function that simply prints out the error text. Those work fine, I've taken them from other work I wrote and they work. However, when I run

```
bash -x myFunction bad parameters
```

it shows that firstError successfully returns an error code of 1, like it is supposed to, but then suddenly switches to return 0. Like this:

```
+ errorCheck bad parameters
+ firstError bad parameters
+ return 1
+ return 0
+ main bad parameters
```

However, when I hardcode it like this:

```
function errorCheck(){
if ! firstError $*
then 
return 1
elif ! secondError $*
then
return 2
fi
```

Then the bash report looks like this:

```
+ errorCheck bad parameters
+ firstError bad parameters
+ return 1
+ return 1
+ errorReport 1
+ echo 'Error 1'
+ exit 1
```

Which is what I want to happen. Why is the return value suddenly switching to 0? Please keep it simple, as I'm new to bash.

Comment: Note `bad parameters` errors are generally telling your something.

Comment: BTW, note that `foo $*` is basically always buggy. Unless you really, **really** know what you're doing, you should use `foo "$@"` instead. (Sometimes `foo "$*"` can be appropriate, if you want to collapse all your arguments into a single string; but the behavior of `foo $*` without quotes -- of combining all your arguments into a single string, splitting that string into individual words, and then expanding each of those words as a glob expression -- is pretty much universally undesirable).

Comment: (as another aside, see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete re: function declaration syntax -- `function foo() {` combines legacy ksh and POSIX sh function declaration syntax in a manner that's compatible with neither; consider adopting either the POSIX form, of `foo() {` with no `function`, or the legacy ksh form of `function foo {` with no `()`).

Answer (score 2):

The `!` operator inverts the exit status of a command. If the `firstError` command returns a non-zero status, the exit status of `! firstError` is `0`, and vice versa. `$?` contains this inverted exit status.

If you want to save the original exit status, put the `if` separately from running the command and put it in a variable.

```
firstError $*
status=$?
if [ $status -ne 0 ]
then
    return $status
fi
secondError $*
status=$?
if [ $status -ne 0 ]
    return $status
fi
```

Another possibility is to use the `||` operator:

```
firstError $* || return
secondError $* || return
```

If `return` isn't given an argument, it defaults to `$?`.

Comment: So is there a better way to set up an if statement to test for a failed test? If I remove the "!" then it counts the error test as a failure, and therefore does not proceed to the "then" statement.

Comment: I ti almost impossible to tell without seeing `firstError` and `secondError`, we are left guessing whether you provide an explicit return or whether the return is simply that of the last command in each. Please provide [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ZaneRodnick-Smith I've updated the answer to show how you can do what you want.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The contents of `firstError` and `secondError` are irrelevant. He just wants this function to call them sequentially until one fails, then return that exit status.

Comment: I'd suggest `|| return`, vs `|| return $?`, since `$?` is the default return value.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Didn't realize that, updated the answer.

Comment: @Barmar That's exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: I often have more complicated error handling/reporting, so I tend to use something like `firstError "$@" || { status=$?; echo "Error #$? in first part of process" >&2; rm "$tmpfile"; return $status; }`